# given a not oriented graph G, find an algorithm that verify if is possible to partition the set of nodes into two sets V1 C V and V2 C V (continue)

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

given a not oriented graph G=(V,E) represented with adjacency list,find an algorithm(that solve the problem in linear time) that verify if is possible to partition the set of nodes into two sets V1 C V and V2 C V with this condition:

- V1 U V2 = V
- V1 intersected V2= void set
- v belong to V1  <=>  for each edge (v,w) in E , w belongs to V2

the algorithm return V1 and V2 if there is a solution

Comment: Is this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bipartite-graph/ helpful?

Comment: yes it help, thanks!